# Ajax set variable from multiple url

Tags: jquery, ajax

I really new to ajax and was wondering if there's a way to avoid using setTimeout in the following.  I need to create two variables from two url's (/blog and /blog/all).  I then need to use these variables together in a separate function.  My (flawed) plan was to make two ajax calls and pass the result into an empty div and then set new variables based off the contents of those div's in order to run my function.  It works but I have to use setTimeout which obviously isn't ideal.  Is there a way to maybe nest one ajax call inside another?  I tried that but no luck.  Here's what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url : "/blog/all",
        success : function (data) {
            var totalPosts = $(data).find('.post-item').length
            console.log("totalPosts: " + totalPosts);
            $('.totalPosts').text(totalPosts);
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        url : "/blog",
        success : function (data) {
            var pagePosts = $(data).find('.post-item').length
            console.log("pagePosts: " + pagePosts);
            $('.pagePosts').text(pagePosts);
        }
    });

    setTimeout(function(){  

        var tPosts = $('.totalPosts').text();
        var pPosts = $('.pagePosts').text();
        console.log("tPosts: " + tPosts);
        console.log("pPosts: " + pPosts);
    }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: Use promises to wait for both AJAX calls to finish.

Comment: Actually, you **shouldn't** be using a timeout in the first place.

Comment: You don't need promises either according to http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ 'as of 1.5 $.ajax implements the Promise interface, giving them all the properties, methods, and behavior of a Promise'. its built in

Comment: which is why he passed `$.ajax` calls to `$.when` in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url : "/blog/all",
        success : function (data1) {
            var totalPosts = $(data1).find('.post-item').length
            console.log("totalPosts: " + totalPosts);
            $('.totalPosts').text(totalPosts);
            $.ajax({
               url : "/blog",
               success : function (data2) {
                  var pagePosts = $(data2).find('.post-item').length
                  console.log("pagePosts: " + pagePosts);
                  $('.pagePosts').text(pagePosts);

                  // Here goes the code that was in timeout
                  var tPosts = $('.totalPosts').text();
                  var pPosts = $('.pagePosts').text();
                  console.log("tPosts: " + tPosts);
                  console.log("pPosts: " + pPosts);
               }
            });
         }
    });
});
```

Comment: should note that this approach takes longer to complete than using promises

Comment: yo dawg i heard you like ajax so i put some ajax in your ajax ;) only joking. if it works it works!

Comment: Actually, I myself agree barman's answer is better, and besides you can't argue with the barman. I just put this together as a viable alternative that *might* make more sense at first.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) to take action when all the AJAX calls complete.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var promise1 = $.ajax({
        url : "/blog/all",
        success : function (data) {
            var totalPosts = $(data).find('.post-item').length
            console.log("totalPosts: " + totalPosts);
            $('.totalPosts').text(totalPosts);
        }
    });

    var promise2 = $.ajax({
        url : "/blog",
        success : function (data) {
            var pagePosts = $(data).find('.post-item').length
            console.log("pagePosts: " + pagePosts);
            $('.pagePosts').text(pagePosts);
        }
    });

    $.when(promise1, promise2).then(function(){  
        var tPosts = $('.totalPosts').text();
        var pPosts = $('.pagePosts').text();
        console.log("tPosts: " + tPosts);
        console.log("pPosts: " + pPosts);
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what happened.

Answer (score 0):

By using success and error callbacks you can guarantee availability of data without relying on timeouts.

If one call depends on the other, why not use built in callbacks? Here is some pseudo code to illustrate

```
var allBlogItems = null;
var getAll = function(){
  $.ajax {
    url : "/blog/all",
    success: function(data){
       allBlogItems = data;
       getBlogThenSetHTML();
     }
    }
  }
 };
 var blogData = null; 
 var getBlogThenSetHTML = function(){
   $.ajax {
    url : "/blog/all",
    success: function(data){
       blogData = data;
       doSomething();
     }
    }
  }
 };

 var doSomething = function(){
   console.log(blogData);
   console.log(allBlogData);
 };
```

This is just a quick and dirty example of course. You can execute your calls in sequence and use the resulting data how you please after both calls have been made.

Encapsulating your data objects in functions will also help with reusability and readability. Nesting ajax calls within ajax calls is hideous.